# Performance Analysis via Core

Tags: haskell, ghc

The following code runs in about 1.5ms on my computer (compiled with GHC 8.0.1 and -02):

```
import Criterion
import Data.Bits
import Data.Int
import Criterion.Main

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain [bench "mybench" $ nf (mybench 3840) (0 :: Int)]

mybench :: Int -> Int -> Double
{-# INLINE mybench #-}
mybench n = go 0 n
  where go s i g | i == 0 = s
                 | otherwise =
                      let (w,_) = f 1 0 g
                          --w = f 1 0 g
                          f mag v gen | mag >= 18446744073709551616000 = (v,gen)
                          --f mag v gen | mag >= 18446744073709551616000 = v
                                      | otherwise = v' `seq` f (mag*18446744073709551616 :: Integer) v' gen where
                                            x = -8499970308474009078 :: Int
                                            v' = (v * 18446744073709551616 + (fromIntegral x + 9223372036854775808))

                          y = fromInteger ((-9223372036854775808) + w `mod` 18446744073709551616)
                          coef = (fromIntegral (9007199254740991 .&. (y::Int64)) :: Double) /  9007199254740992
                          z = 2.0 * (-0.5 + coef)
                      in go (z+s) (i-1) g
```

However, if I use the commented alternates of `w` and `f`, the code runs in ~31μs! This was surprising to me since I changed very little, and because `f` runs twice for each of 3,840 iterations (i.e., the code is barely used).

I went to the core to investigate. Here's the relevant portions of `-ddump-simpl` from the [slow version](http://lpaste.net/181325) and [fast version](http://lpaste.net/181324).

Unfortunately, I can't see from the core what is making such a huge difference. The primary difference that I see is that in the fast version, GHC has realized that `f` doesn't need the `gen` argument. But surely that can't make a 45x/2 orders of magnitude performance difference.

The source code is a bit contrived (several args aren't needed or used), so my main question is about the core: I don't see any differences that would indicate such a drastic performance difference. What am I missing when analyzing the core? As a followup, what could I do at the source level of the first/slow version to get it to perform like the second/fast version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like in the fast version GHC lifted the computation:

```
 y = fromInteger ((-9223372036854775808) + w `mod` 18446744073709551616)
```

out of the definition of `go`. Just look at where `modInteger` and `plusInteger` occur in both dumps.

It looks like in the assignment `w = f 1 0 g` it inlined the definition of `f` so that it doesn't have to compute `w` on each call to `go`.
More specifically, `f 1 0 g` doesn't depend on any the parameters to `go` - ie. `s`, `i` or `g`, and so it's computation can be lifted out.

Even though `g` is passed to `f` in the expression `f 1 0 g`, it doesn't actually get used.

Comment: I see that that happened, but why does that have any performance implications? Shouldn't the "inlined" version (from the slow core) be no slower?

Comment: GHC moved the computation of `w` to be outside of the call to `go`.  Even though you've inlined `mybench`, it is still recomputing `w` every time `go` is called. This isn't happening in the fast version.

Comment: So when GHC factors out the computation, I get *sharing*. That makes sense!

Comment: @Eric if you add `{-# options_ghc -fno-full-laziness #-}`, you disable lifting-out and the two code performs the same. My general advice is to enable `no-full-laziness` for numeric and really high-performance code and control lifting manually.

Comment: @AndrásKovács They do perform the same...but they both take 6.1ms, 5x slower than the original slow version! Doesn't seem like good advice to me, what am I missing?

Comment: @Eric of course you have to lift manually in that case! The benefit comes from knowing precisely where computation takes place, and also from being able to prevent mishaps like fusion failing because of lifting. You can't develop a good intuition for numeric performance if GHC keeps surprising you with opaque lifting.